# HTML5 - Access Camera

Tags: javascript, html, camera

I'd like to access camera with HTML and JavaScript.
I've seen [this example](https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera), but it doesn't work in Chrome.
I have tried this, too:

```
<img src="">
<video></video>
<canvas style="display:none;"></canvas>

<script>
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var localMediaStream = null;

  function snapshot() {
    if (localMediaStream) {
      ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
      // "image/webp" works in Chrome.
      // Other browsers will fall back to image/png.
      document.querySelector('img').src = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');
    }
  }

  video.addEventListener('click', snapshot, false);

  // Not showing vendor prefixes or code that works cross-browser.
  navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    localMediaStream = stream;
  }, errorCallback);
</script>
```

Who can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `errorCallback` function.

```
function errorCallback(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

I added this and got an error:
[image]

To access userMedia you have to have [https](https://www.google.ee/search?q=https). I tried running it [here (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/u2aLufn4/) and works for me.